# Remove all SAP GUI versions

Tags: powershell, uninstallation, sap-gui

I'm working on a script to remove all versions of SAP GUI here is what I have

```
$uninstall=Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object displayname -like "*SAP*" | select uninstallstring
foreach ($app in $uninstall)
{
    Start-Process "$uninstall" -verb runas -Wait

}


Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:5 char:9
+         Start-Process "$uninstall" -verb runas -Wait
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:5 char:9
+         Start-Process "$uninstall" -verb runas -Wait
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process],   InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: SAP is a company. Good luck trying to uninstall that...

Comment: Sorry SAP GUI is the application.

Comment: Check the Installation Guide - the installer has a command line parameter for this (/uninstall /all, I believe).

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to learn PS so its something I would like to complete with PS. I found the command thats in the install guide nwsapsetup.exe /uninstall /all /nodlg /force and that does work but I would like to do it with PS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do it like this:

```
foreach ($app in $uninstall) {
    Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe' -ArgumentList '/C',$app -Verb RunAs;
}
```

The problem is that `UninstallString` typically contains the path to an executable *with arguments*.  Neither `Start-Process`, nor `Invoke-Expression`, nor the call operator (`&`) like that.  They want the path to the executable, and then the arguments to be in another list.

Compare:

```
Start-Process 'msiexec.exe /?';
```

With:

```
Start-Process 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe' -ArgumentList '/C','msiexec.exe /?';
```

The other option is to try to parse `UninstallString` and split the arguments up, but that's pretty gross.

Comment: What does this piece mean?

-ArgumentList '/C'

Comment: @user770022 The `-ArgumentList` parameter specifies the array of arguments, in order, to pass to `cmd.exe` when it starts.  The `/C` tells `cmd.exe` to carry out the command and then terminate. See `cmd.exe /?` for more information about that.  What my workaround is doing is starting the command line and passing the uninstall string to that to execute, so PowerShell is starting CMD, and CMD is starting the uninstallation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to try

```
Start-Process "$app" -Verb RunAs -Wait
```

`$uninstall` represents the complete collection, `$app` is a single item.

Also, `$uninstall` does not hold what you expect, you should try like this:

```
regPath = "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"

$uninstall = Get-ItemProperty $regPath |
    Where-Object DisplayName -like "*SAP*" |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty UninstallString -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

foreach ($app in $uninstall) {
    #do something with $app
}
```

`-ExpandProperty` makes sure you only get the `UninstallString` values listed in `$uninstall`.

`-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` removes the errors caused by missing `UninstallString` values.

Last but not least, I have tried to run the command with `Start-Process` and it fails, you will have to use another method to execute the uninstall command.

Comment: Same error but Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:5 char:9
+         Start-Process "$app" -verb runas -Wait

Comment: Soda... The issue is from this `select uninstallstring`..... Update your answer with that

Comment: What I answered is what struck me first. I had to run the code at least once to spot the other problems. Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you for being helpful.

Comment: I prefer to use WMI to do this but that's another subject. Some good advice is included in Bacon Bits' answer. Edit : check my answer for this question for the WMI method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679597/uninstalling-using-get-wmiobject/34680914#34680914

Comment: $app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "Vendor = 'SAP AG'" only gives me

Comment: IdentifyingNumber : {A47A9101-6EB5-4314-BDA1-297880FBB908}
Name              : Microsoft redistributable runtime DLLs VS2008 SP1(x86)
Vendor            : SAP AG
Version           : 9.0
Caption           : Microsoft redistributable runtime DLLs VS2008 SP1(x86)

Comment: You should try to understand the code before running it :). If you see this I think it's running properly and uninstalling the application. Sorry if this methods fails you. Please create a new question if you have an issue with this other piece of code.

Comment: I think the problem with the WMI method is that Win32_Product is not a comprehensive listing of all software that has been installed on the system.  It's not even a list of software that's been installed with Windows Installer.  Windows' Add/Remove Programs list never matches whats in Win32_Product.

Comment: The list is not as complete as the uninstall registry keys, but I still find this method useful in many cases.